# easy_install not working-windows 8 64 bit

Tags: python-2.7

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, so I apologize in advance.  Here's the situation:

I'm trying to install some python modules to work with excel documents, however, I can't even get the easy_install command to work.  Both python and python\scripts are in my system path, and I've run the setup tools script several times.  I've checked the scripts folder, and it contains both the easy_install script and the .exe file.  However, when I try to run it from the command line, I receive a traceback error:

```
>>> easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    easy_install
NameError: name 'easy_install' is not defined`
```

this is a 64-bit Windows 8 machine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Posting the traceback is really useful.

Comment: Why do you have "easy_install" in python code? It's a shell command.

Comment: What is test2.py, what is the exact command line you are using ? People here will help you gladly, but *you* have to provide us with details. But not too much. Filter them out, and tell us what you did to try to fix the problem. +Welcome to StakOverflow !

Comment: I had a text editor open and just copy-pasted the error.  I'll include the error from the shell above

Comment: Why not use `pip` instead?

Comment: honestly, because I want to understand the error, and I'm not sure if pip will give me the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

easy_install is a shell command .

To use easy_install on windows follow these steps:

press `window + r` and type `cmd` then press `Enter`

probably easy_install.exe is not in your system path, so type the full path to easy_install:

`C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe name_of_the_package` then press Enter.

I suggest you to read this: http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#windows-notes